# WSL2: Install fonts for Linux GUI app using X server

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, xorg, windows-subsystem-for-linux, x-server

I'm on Windows 11 and I installed the latest version of WSL (using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS). I also enabled GUI apps according to this official [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps).

I'm trying to run Xfoil, which uses X server windows for graphical output. It can be installed on Ubuntu using `sudo apt-get install xfoil`.

When running xfoil, i.e.:

```
$ xfoil
$ naca 4412
$ oper
$ a
$ 0
```

I get the following error when Xfoil tries to plot to Windows:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  45 (X_OpenFont)
  Serial number of failed request:  26
  Current serial number in output stream:  28
```

It seems like the X server in WSL (not sure which one it is) does not have the right fonts. I have tried installing fonts using
`sudo apt-get install xfonts-base xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-cyrillic`
and rebooting, without success.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up all available font packages using
`apt list | grep xfonts`

Eventually,

`sudo apt install xfonts-75dpi-transcoded xfonts-100dpi-transcoded`

solved it for me after rebooting.